# Why does UIView.StringSize need to run on the UI thread?

Tags: xamarin.ios

If I run `UIView.StringSize` from within some async code like a `Task.ContinueWith`, it will blow up with a `UIKitThreadAccessException` because that method starts with a call to `UIApplication.EnsureUIThread` ("Go to declaration" in MonoDevelop; I'm not sure the license allows me to post it here).

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // Blows up discretely...nothing written to application output.
    // Also blows up for UIViews that exist only in code (not rendered).
    SizeF textSize = someView.StringSize(someString, someFont, new SizeF(someView.Bounds.Width, float.MaxValue), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
    Console.WriteLine(textSize);
});
```

If I wrap this simplified version in `InvokeOnMainThread`, all is well, but I definitely have times when I want to measure some text without that call. As well, I fully understand the [exception's purpose](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2012/Sep-10.html) and it has saved me a bunch of hassle when called something deep within async code before, but in this case the use of `EnsureUIThread` here seems unnecessary. If I simply restate that call as a hit on the `NSString` class, it will happily run outside the UI thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // Outputs expected size data: "{Width=##, Height=##}".
    using (NSString nssSomeString = new NSString(someString)) {
        SizeF textSize = nssSomeString.StringSize(someFont, new SizeF(someView.Bounds.Width, float.MaxValue), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
        Console.WriteLine(textSize);
    }
});
```

The code for `UIView.StringSize` appears to do roughly the same `NSString` work and there doesn't appear to be anything blatantly UI-thread-oriented. Is there something I am missing that would require this version of the method to be called from the UI thread?

#### Edit (2013-01-17):

I [filed a bug with Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9657) just to see their response. It sounds like they are looking into marking this method as `ThreadSafe`.

Comment: I think all UI-realated code needs to be ran in main thread. It has been mentioned a few times in Apple's WWDC Videos.

Comment: That's actually the point of this question; is this actually UI-related? In MonoTouch, it seems like this is a `UIView` convenience shortcut (which it is) to the `NSString` method that isn't limited to the UI thread.

Comment: I don't think it matters, as you get access to things in your main view through that NSString-like UIView in MonoTouch, it must have some link to the actual UIView object.

Comment: If you "Go to definition" in MonoDevelop, you can see the actual code (or at least a decompiled version of it).

Comment: Maybe it's time for me to dig it up, kinda fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI restriction on the `StringSize` method is indeed unnecessary. Xamarin has already [fixed this for "v6.0.10+"](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9657).

> We already detremined that DrawString (drawInRect:* selectors) were fine from
>   other threads. StringSize is a subset of that feature so it should be safe to.
>   Future versions (6.0.10+) will be marked as [ThreadSafe].

Until you are coding against the updated version, the `NSString` version will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `UIView` is being access from a thread it wasn't created on.  Since you are creating `NSString` in the background thread, your second example will work fine and is recommended. (Although I don't think you should try to access `someView.Bounds` from a background thread either)

I suspect this would also work:

```
var bounds = someView.Bounds; //UI thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // Outputs expected size data: "{Width=##, Height=##}".
    using (UIView view = new UIView()) {
        SizeF textSize = view.StringSize(someString, someFont, new SizeF(bounds.Width, float.MaxValue), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
        Console.WriteLine(textSize);
    }
});
```

But I would just stick with `NSString`:

```
var bounds = someView.Bounds; //UI thread
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // Outputs expected size data: "{Width=##, Height=##}".
    using (NSString nssSomeString = new NSString(someString)) {
        SizeF textSize = nssSomeString.StringSize(someFont, new SizeF(bounds.Width, float.MaxValue), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
        Console.WriteLine(textSize);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm definitely sold on using `NSString.StringSize`, and I will also agree that `Bounds` could be "in limbo" when hit outside the UI thread, but I would still argue you aren't actually accessing anything on the `UIView` itself that would open one up to a problem in this case; you are just calling a method that happens to be a part of that class. I'll toss a bug at Xamarin to see if there is some other reason for that choice.

Comment: No, this is not a bug. Accessing a UI object from a thread it was not created on is not allowed. This rule has existed in every UI platform I've worked with: iOS, Android, WPF, even back to WinForms.

Comment: I would argue that logic on semantics ("access" vs. "manipulate"), but I'm trying to argue that very point isn't relevant in this case. Calling `StringSize` is not manipulating a `UIView` object in any way, it is simply calling a utility method (which calls what appears to be another, UI-independent, `NSString` utility method) that happens to be made available through `UIView` instances. No UI changes appear to be possible through the use of that method. If so, ensuring it is called from the UI thread would be completely unnecessary.

Comment: I think this is still something Apple has defined: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html There is a section stating these methods should be only called from a main thread. I believe Xamarin is checking against the thread the object was created on to throw this exception for you.