# Creating a non-displayed, sized, UIView outside the UI thread?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is there a way to manipulate the size of a non-displayed `UIView` from outside the UI thread prior to adding it to a displayed view?

While working through some asynchronous iOS code, I thought I would try to have an async method build up a `UIView` that would be displayed later [on the UI thread]. In this case, and this appears to be the "gotcha", it was a `UILabel` where I want to give it a predetermined frame size derived from a [`StringSize` call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14385826/48700). Unfortunately, the `UIView` constructor that takes a `RectangleF frame` calls `UIApplication.EnsureOnUIThread` first.

```
// Throws UIKitThreadAccessException on Frame-setting UILabel constructor.
Task<UILabel> getView = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    //... Do some async fun (e.g., call web service for some data for someNSString)

    SizeF requiredStringSize = someNSString.StringSize(someFont, new SizeF(maxWidth, float.MaxValue), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
    RectangleF someViewFrame = new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, requiredStringSize)
    return new UILabel(someViewFrame);
});
```

Since I don't really need to set a valid location at the point of this task execution, I figured I could avoid setting the frame in the constructor and set the size afterwards. Unfortunately, you only seem to be able to set size by modifying `UIView.Frame` as a whole. While the parameter-less constructor does not make this UI thread call, as soon as I try to set the `Frame` to the size needed, the `UIView.Frame` accessor does and it blows up.

```
// Also throws UIKitThreadAccessException, this time when setting the Frame directly.
Task<UILabel> getView = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    //...do all the above stuff...
    UIView someView = new UILabel();
    someView.Frame = new RectangleF(someView.Frame.Location, requiredStringSize);
});
```

I've already decided to make my code more specific to the case at hand and use a `Task<string>` instead, letting the displaying code (run on the UI thread) handle the view creation, but it would be nice to know if this is possible since it would make the code I am writing more extensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIKit is not designed to be used outside of the main thread.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I've seen some bizarre behaviour creep in when this rule is ignored, so I strongly advise against this.

Comment: I definitely see major potential for bugs. I have a heavy JavaScript background, so I was very accustomed to building up UIs outside the rendered DOM before putting them in place. Of course, that is all on the same thread (and incremental live DOM updates would be slower), so it may be the only reason that is so encouraged. That was the perspective I was trying to apply here, but it was more a curiosity than anything vital.

Comment: **strongly** ++ there's nothing but pain trying to work around this (what *seems* to work only fails on different devices).